# Recognizing which XSD choice was selected in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, unmarshalling

I use Java for generating a schema which cannot change. This is one of the XSD choice element field:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "A", type = String.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "B", type = Integer.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "C", type = String.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "D", type = String.class)
})
protected Object aOrBOrCOrD;
```

During unmarshalling using the same class, I need to recognize which choice value(A, B, C or D) was sent in the XML request as the different choice element are processed differently.

Note that I cannot use instanceof to know since 3 of the 4 choice elements are Strings.